I want to get adjacency list with pytorch geo. Is there any method in pytorch do that or anything to convert adjacency matrix but optimized, not loop
I want to get adjacency list with pytorch geo. Is there any method in pytorch to do that or anything to convert adjacency matrix but optimized, not loop?
Like this :
import numpy as np
import networkx as nx


def adjacency_matrix_to_list(adj_matrix):
    # Créer un graphe à partir de la matrice d'adjacence
    graph = nx.from_numpy_matrix(adj_matrix)

    # Convertir le graphe en liste d'adjacence
    adj_list = nx.to_dict_of_lists(graph)

    return adj_list


There is No Straightforward way. Please, Go through the following methods.
Using torch.tensor
Method 1 :
import torch
from scipy.sparse import csr_matrix
import torch
from numpy import nonzero
import networkx as nx
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


adj_matrix = torch.tensor([[0, 1, 0],
                           [1, 0, 1],
                           [0, 1, 0]])

# Convert adjacency matrix to adjacency list
src_indices, dst_indices = adj_matrix.nonzero().unbind(-1)
"""
split_sizes : it tells us how many outgoing edges (neighbors) each node has in the graph.
minlength=adj_matrix.size(0) => the same length as the number of nodes in the graph.
torch.bincount: This function is used to count the number of occurrences 
of each element in the input tensor src_indices.

It counts the occurrences of each unique value in src_indices.
"""
split_sizes = torch.bincount(input=src_indices, minlength=adj_matrix.size(0))
"""
counts the occurrences of each unique value in src_indices
"""
adj_list = torch.split(dst_indices, split_sizes.tolist())

# Convert adjacency list tensors to regular lists
res = [x.tolist() for x in adj_list]
print(res)#[[1], [0, 2], [1]]

Method 2:
from scipy.sparse import csr_matrix
from numpy import nonzero
import torch

adj_matrix = torch.tensor([[0, 1, 0],
                           [1, 0, 1],
                           [0, 1, 0]])

mask = (adj_matrix != 0)
source_indices  = mask.nonzero(as_tuple=True)[0]
print(source_indices )
destination_indices = mask.nonzero(as_tuple = True)[1]
print(destination_indices)
"""
It holds a tensor where each row represents an edge in the graph. 
The first element in each row is the source node index, 
and the second element is the destination node index.
dim=1: This argument specifies that the tensors should be stacked along 
the first dimension (columns in this case)
"""
edge_index = torch.stack(tensors = (source_indices,destination_indices), dim=1)
print(edge_index)
"""
tensor([[0, 1],
        [1, 0],
        [1, 2],
        [2, 1]])
"""
"""
.sum(dim=1): This performs a summation along dimension 1 (columns) for each row.
It counts the number of True values (non-zero elements) in each row.
adj_list  : Stores the number of outgoing edges (neighbors) for each node in the graph. 
"""
adj_list = (adj_matrix != 0 ).sum(dim=1).tolist()
print(adj_list)#[1, 2, 1]
adj_list = [[] for _ in adj_list]
print(adj_list)#[[], [], []]
"""
src: Represents the source node index (the node where the edge originates).
dst: Represents the destination node index (the node where the edge points to)
"""

# Scatter destination nodes into their corresponding lists
for i, (src, dst) in enumerate(edge_index):
    adj_list[src.item()].append(dst.item())  # Append destination node directly

print(adj_list)#[[1], [0, 2], [1]]
    

Without Using torch.tensor
import numpy as np
from scipy.sparse import csr_matrix 

# Example with sparse CSR matrix
sparse_adj_matrix = csr_matrix([[0, 1, 0],
                                [1, 0, 1],
                                [0, 1, 0]])

def adjacency_matrix_to_list(adj_matrix):
    if not isinstance(adj_matrix, csr_matrix):
    # Convert dense matrix to sparse CSR format for potential efficiency gains
     adj_matrix = csr_matrix(adj_matrix)

    num_nodes = adj_matrix.shape[0]
    print('num_nodes :', num_nodes) #3
    
    # Extract neighboring nodes using CSR matrix attributes
    split_indices = np.split(adj_matrix.indices,adj_matrix.indptr[1:-1] )
    print('split_indices :',split_indices) #split_indices : [array([1]), array([0, 2]), array([1])]

    # Convert split_indices to a list of lists
    adj_list = [arr.tolist() for arr in split_indices]

    return adj_list

adj_list = adjacency_matrix_to_list(sparse_adj_matrix)
print(adj_list)  # Output: [[1], [0, 2], [1]]

Or less efficient
adj_matrix = np.array([[0, 1, 0],
                       [1, 0, 1],
                       [0, 1, 0]])


adj_list = [list(np.where(row)[0]) for row in adj_matrix]

print(adj_list)  # Output: [[1], [0, 2], [1]]


By not using loops I presume you mean avoiding nested loops like this:
import torch

def adjacency_matrix_to_list_with_loops(adj_matrix):
    num_nodes = adj_matrix.shape[0]
    adj_list = []
    for i in range(num_nodes):
        neighbors = []
        for j in range(num_nodes):
            if adj_matrix[i][j] == 1:
                neighbors.append(j)
        adj_list.append(neighbors)
    return adj_list

If you don't wish to use an additional library like networkx then you will need to use at least one loop to iterate over the matrix nodes.
The result of torch.nonzero is a tensor with shape (n, 1) (where n is the number of non-zero elements). The .squeeze() method removes the singleton dimension, resulting in a tensor of shape (n,).
import torch

def adjacency_matrix_to_list(adj_matrix):
    num_nodes = adj_matrix.shape[0]
    adj_list = []
    for i in range(num_nodes):
        # Find indices of non-zero elements in the i-th row
        neighbors = torch.nonzero(adj_matrix[i]).squeeze()
        adj_list.append(neighbors.tolist())
    return adj_list

The performance of this method will depend on the size of the graph and the sparsity of the adjacency matrix. For very large graphs, the networkx solution may be a more optimized approach.

You can't avoid using a loop. At best you can execute the loop at a lower level that runs faster than standard python.
You can use torch.nonzero to find nonzero values and iterate over those to build the output dict.
import torch
from collections import defaultdict

# ie init random adjacency matrix
adj_matrix = (torch.rand(10,10)>0.8).float()

# grab nonzero values
nonzero_vals = torch.nonzero(adj_matrix)

# init output adjacency list
adj_list = defaultdict(set)

# add nonzero rows/cols to output dict 
for (row, col) in nonzero_vals.tolist():
    adj_list[row].update([col])
    if row != col:
        adj_list[col].update([row])
    
adj_list = {k:list(v) for k,v in adj_list.items()}

